# AngularJS: Conditionally show Aria-describedBy

Tags: angularjs, accessibility

In AngularJS, I'm using a `#sample` input field, and if that field has error, I'm showing an error message in `#error` span class.

```
<input id="sample" />
<span id="error" ng-if="validateSample()">Show error</>
```

My requirement is, that if there is an error, I want to dynamically add `aria-describedBy="error"` to input field. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: use ng-show instead of ng-if?

Comment: I don't think that'll be a great solution for the scenario when the error message is not shown(i.e. there is no error). Because even then, the screen-readers will treat the error message as the label for the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're after the [aria-invalid attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-invalid_attribute).